# Virtual tables memory location

Tags: c++

Given the following code:

```
namespace Example1 {

class Base1 {
public:
    Base1() {}
    virtual ~Base1() {}
protected:
    float data_Base1;
};

class Base2 {
public:
    Base2() {}
    virtual ~Base2() {}
protected:
    float data_Base2;
};

class Derived : public Base1, public Base2 {
public:
    Derived() {}
    virtual ~Derived() {}
protected:
    float data_Derived;
};

class Derived2 : public Base1 {
public:
    Derived2() {}
    virtual ~Derived2() {}
protected:
    float data_Derived2;
};

}

int main (void)
{
using namespace Example1;

Base2* pbase2 = new Derived;        
Base1* b = new Base1();
      Base1* b2 = new Base1();
Derived* d = new Derived;
Derived* d2= new Derived;

Derived2* dd = new Derived2;
}
```

With visual studio 2012's compiler , it seems that under multiple inheritance, a derived class contains n-1 additional virtual tables. and that is exactly what happens with Derived class.

But it also seem to happen with Derived2 (Which only inherits from Base1 class)

here's dd memory map:

```
Example1::Base1
  __vfptr
     [0]     0x00c4127b
```

here's b memory map:

```
__vfptr
    [0]      0x00c411ae
```

As you can see, the address of the first virtual table slot is different.. 
b and b2 for example, has the same virtual table.

Ok , so now for the two questions:

1) Why don't they share the same Base1 virtual table? (Derived2 and Base1 objects)

2) Why is that even necessary for a derived class to hold n-1 virtual tables ? (When N indicates the number of classes the Derived class inherits from)

thanks!

Comment: btw. those are  implementation details and may differ among implementations, and the best to ask is probably the manufacturer, we here can mostly guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `Derived2` is of another type than `Base1`, so it needs some other information apart from the virtual functions table. Second, at least `Derived2`'s destructor is another function than the one from `Base1`, so even if there were only the virtual functions in the table, that entry *has* to be differnt.
I am not sure about how MSVC implements RTTI on polymorphic types, but there has to be some identifcation of the type different to virtual functions, e.g. to enable `dynamic_cast`s. So that first entry could very well be the pointer to the RTTI. I have no MSVC around at the moment, but you could try this:

```
struct Base {
  virtual void foo() {};
  virtual void bar() {};
  virtual ~Base();
};

struct Derived {
  virtual void foo() {};
  virtual ~Derived();
};

int main() {
  Base* b1 = new Base;
  Base* b2 = new Derived;
};
```

Now inspect the first four or five elements of the `__vfptr`'s of the two created objects, my guess is you will see one entry that is the same - it's the pointer to `Base::bar`. The others (Pointers to RTTI, foo and destructor) should be different.
Here comes some gueswork: *Maybe* you can see a different region in memory the pointers point to, since the RTTI pointers might point to the data segment, while the virtual function pointers point to code segment.

**Update:** there need not be an entry for RTTI in the vtable itself - it might be possible that some compilers implement RTTI just by *comparing* the addresses of the vtables.

Answer (score 0):

Each class will have it's own vtable. In this case, each class has a unique virtual destructor, so that in itself means that the vtable needs to be the different. If you were to construct a class that didn't have any virtual functions that are different, it is possible that the compiler may decide to "reuse" the same vtable. But not guaranteed.

If a class is deriving from more than one class, then there needs to be a vtable for each class that has virtual functions of any kind. This is so that the virtual functions of both base-classes can be called if the class is converted (either by using a pointer to the base or a dynamic_cast) into one of the base classes.

Note also: How the compiler deals with vtables is entirely up to the compiler, and no guarantees are made about ANY aspect of how they work.

Comment: If the compiler uses the vtable for RTTI (which afaik most/all compilers do), they will have to be different for different classes, even if all of their virtual functions are the same, i.e. no virtual dtor and no virtual function overridden or added in the derived class.